# How to distinguish free-standing composite types from table composite types in pg_type?

Tags: postgresql

When querying `pg_type`, I'm interested in identifying free-standing composite types (user-defined) and not those which are created along with tables. Perhaps there is a way to lookup `pg_class` (with `typrelid`) which might help but it's not apparent how I might do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Composite types that belong to tables have an *internal* dependency on the table in `pg_depend`. You simply have to exclude such types:

```
SELECT t.oid::regtype
FROM pg_type AS t
WHERE t.typtype = 'c'
   AND t.typnamespace NOT IN
          ('pg_catalog'::regnamespace, 'pg_toast'::regnamespace)
   AND NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT 1 FROM pg_depend AS d
          WHERE d.objid = t.oid
            AND d.classid = 'pg_type'::regclass
            AND d.refclassid = 'pg_class'::regclass
            AND d.deptype = 'i');
```

Answer (score 4):

i believe i've found the answer - `pg_class` (which can be joined to `pg_type ON pg_type.typrelid = pg_class.oid`) has a column called `relkind` which provides:

```
r = ordinary table
i = index
S = sequence
v = view
c = composite type *** identifies free-standing composite type
t = TOAST table
```

This query identifies custom (free-standing) types:

```
select t.typname, t.typtype, t.typcategory, t.typrelid, c.relname, c.relkind
from pg_type t
left join pg_class c on c.oid = t.typrelid
where t.typtype = 'c' and c.relkind = 'c';
```